# Libgdx - stackOverFlow when I use .isPressed()

Tags: java, android, libgdx, touch-event

I'm coding a Menu using the latest version of Libgdx. Each screen (MainMenuScreen, OptionsMenuScreen, CreditsMenuScreen) contains some buttons. Each button should change the screen.
If I'm on MainMenuScreen and I press "credits", I get the CreeditsMenuScreen. But when I use "back button" to get back in the Main Menu, I get a stackOverflow error.

Here is some parts of the code:

```
//In the MainMenuScreen.java: 
    if( creditsButton.isPressed() )  {
      menuManager.setScreen("credits");
    }

//In the CreditsMenuScreen.java I have
    if( backButton.isPressed() )  {
                menuManager.setScreen("main");
            }
```

Here is the error. I think it's connected to the touchevent but I don't know how to fix it..

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:133)
Caused by: java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at org.lwjgl.BufferChecks.checkDirect(BufferChecks.java:138)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(GL20.java:856)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglGL20.glVertexAttribPointer(LwjglGL20.java:829)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram.setVertexAttribute(ShaderProgram.java:657)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.VertexArray.bind(VertexArray.java:115)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.bind(Mesh.java:380)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.bind(Mesh.java:371)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.render(Mesh.java:479)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.Mesh.render(Mesh.java:449)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.flush(SpriteBatch.java:975)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch.setTransformMatrix(SpriteBatch.java:1037)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.resetTransform(Group.java:210)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Group.draw(Group.java:58)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.scenes.scene2d.Stage.draw(Stage.java:128)
    at com.rander.GameMenu.MainMenuScreen.show(MainMenuScreen.java:86)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.rander.GameMenu.MenuManager.setScreen(MenuManager.java:44)
    at com.rander.GameMenu.CreditsMenuScreen.show(CreditsMenuScreen.java:74)
```

Comment: On the main screen, is there another button located in the same position as the back button from the credits page?

Comment: I don't think your problem is actually with the `.isPressed()`, looking at the stacktrace, I would suggest taking a closer look at the 3 locations within your code (CreditsMenuScreen, MenuManager and MainMenuScreen).

Comment: No, they are not in the same locations.

Answer (score 3):

When you switch from one screen back to the the other, the other one has not had `update()` called on it since it last called `setScreen()` in response to its button press, so its button is still pressed. So the screens will keep switching back and forth because both buttons are in pressed state and never get an opportunity to release.

Instead of using `isPressed()`, add a ChangeListener on each button, and in the listener, override `public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor)` and change the screen there. Like this:

```
/// in screen constructor
creditsButton.addListener(new ChangeListener(){
    public void changed (ChangeEvent event, Actor actor){
        menuManager.setScreen("credits");
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried but menuManager.setScreen("credits"); doesn't work.

Comment: "Doesn't work" means what? I don't know how your menu manager class behaves internally.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem (I added the super.render() in the render method) but now, every screen is getting flicking when the mouse is moving in the window.

Here is the MenuManager class:

```
public class MenuManager {
    private static MenuManager uniqueInstance;
    HashMap<String, Screen> menuMap;
    Game game;

    private MenuManager(Game game) {
        this.game = game;
        menuMap = new HashMap<String, Screen>();

    }

    public static MenuManager getInstance(Game game) {
        if(uniqueInstance == null) {
            uniqueInstance = new MenuManager(game);
        }
        return uniqueInstance;
    }

    public void addMenuItem(String type, Screen screen) {
        menuMap.put(type, screen);
    }
    public void removeMenuItem(String type) {
        Screen remove = menuMap.remove(type);
    }

    public Screen getScreen(String type) {
        return menuMap.get(type);
    }

    public void setScreen(String type) {
        game.setScreen(getScreen(type));

    }

}
```

And here is the main class:

```
public class TestGame extends Game {
    MenuManager menuManager;
    Screen mainMenuScreen;
    Screen creditsMenuScreen;
    Screen optionsMenuScreen;


    @Override
    public void create() {
        Gdx.graphics.setContinuousRendering(false);
        menuManager = MenuManager.getInstance(this);
        mainMenuScreen = new MainMenuScreen(menuManager);
        creditsMenuScreen = new CreditsMenuScreen(menuManager);
        optionsMenuScreen = new OptionsMenuScreen(menuManager);
        menuManager.addMenuItem("main", mainMenuScreen);
        menuManager.addMenuItem("credits", creditsMenuScreen);
        menuManager.addMenuItem("options", optionsMenuScreen);
        //Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        //Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        setScreen(menuManager.getScreen("main"));
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);

    }

    @Override
    public void render () {
        super.render(); //important!

    }


    @Override
    public void pause() {
        //super.pause();
    }

    @Override
    public void resume() {
        //super.resume();
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        super.dispose();
    }


}
```

Comment: If you have a new problem, you should post that as a separate question. There's no means of adequately answering a question in an answer on this site.